# Laravel + JWT - Invalid_token error while calling next get API with received token

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using jwt-auth token with laravel 5. I have followed all installation steps mentioned here: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation.

1) Called an APIs for login and received a token

2) While using this token - Called user API with Authorization Bearer {token}  and getting response 
{"error": "token_invalid"
}

Note : Tried in postman client

```
**route.php**

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function(){

Route::resource('authenticate','AuthenticateController', ['only' =>['index']]);

Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});

**AuthenticateController.php**
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
    // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
    // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it

     $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);
    }
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function index()
  {
    //
    $users = User::all();
    return $users;

   }
  // Login API
  public function authenticate(Request $request)
  {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

### kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
   // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class
  ];
}
?>
```

### .htaccess

Added this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: Where is the code generation part? Are you sure you are generating valid tokens?

Comment: Above authenticate method will return a token and checked token signature at jwt.io and it says - verfied

Comment: I have added all data you mentioned in separate answers to the question. Once approved please delete the separate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable the CSRF middleware from your Kernel. It is the one throwing the error not JWT-Auth:

### kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Its being modified after installed jwt-auth.

Comment: are you sure the Authorization bearer is base64 encoded?

Comment: Did you follow the Apache configuration mentioned [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication)

Comment: I have mentioned the apache changes in .htaccess file.

Comment: For the sake of testing, would you pass the token as query string and check it out?

Comment: can you please give me a dummy example ? it would be easy to understand. Thanks

Comment: Sure, that's very simple, instead of passing the token in the header, instead call the API like that: `http://api.mysite.com/me?token={yourtokenhere}`

Comment: http://dev.laravel/api/authenticate?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvZGV2LmxhcmF2ZWxcL2FwaVwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NTA2MjM0MzgsImV4cCI6MTQ1MDYyNzAzOCwibmJmIjoxNDUwNjIzNDM4LCJqdGkiOiJkN2YxODA3YWI2OTg0MDhhODU4NGIxZDNmNjQzOWYyZSJ9.5TR7VAhQ_mZmkeQlk8Ensy44f1xvJ5-tdHNpjmhRpcI  - Still says , token_invalid. Did i missed anything ? i'm using postman to test this.

Comment: What if you removed the middleware from Controller, will it still throw errors?

Comment: If i'll remove middleware - I'm getting all the users.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
   // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class
  ];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it was that i was not sending the token on every request. Make sure you have in the request the header:

[image]

I solve it saving the token in the localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', 'asjdajd9u81911d1noaoshdoqh1d1291y9dh1')
```

And then sending it in the headers.